# Why is state being updated to latest message if I use the spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application in which there is a form with some fields along with validation. However, the validations are not working as I expect them to work. The code is below:

```
state = {
  user: null,
  errors: {}
}

onSubmitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Check if first Name is returned empty
  if (this.state.user.name.trim().length === 0) {
    this.setState({
      errors: {
        ...this.state.errors,
        name: "This field is required"
      }
    });
  }
  //Check if last name is returned empty
  if (this.state.user.surname.trim().length === 0) {
    this.setState({
      errors: {
        ...this.state.errors,
        surname: "This field is required"
      }
    });
    return;
  }
}
```

Now when I do not provide both the input fields and leave them blank, I expect my state to be showing both error messages i.e `errors: {name: "This field is required", surname: "This field is required"}`

But I am only getting the recent error that is for a surname. So my result shows like `errors: {surname: "This field is required"}`

Why is it overriding the first error message? Any help would be appreciated. The code for input field is not shown as they are just input tags with onChange event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `this.setState` calls in the `onSubmitHandler` will be batched together.

From the [`React Docs - setState():`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
> update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
> delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
> does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall

So when you do `...this.state.errors`, `this.state.errors` in both `if` blocks, refers to an empty object. As a result, you only see `surname` key in the `errors` object in the state.

You can fix this problem by copying the `this.state.errors` object, add keys in the copied object and then pass that copied object to `this.setState`.

```
onSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // clone the "errors" object
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    
    //Check if first Name is returned empty
    if(this.state.user.name.trim().length === 0) {
         errors.name = "This field is required";
    }
            
    //Check if last name is returned empty
    if(this.state.user.surname.trim().length === 0) {
        errors.surname = "This field is required";
    }

    this.setState({ errors });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the second spread still uses the old value of this.state.errors as it has not changed yet. Both setStates may be (in your case : definately were) doing the state updates later, after the onSubmitHandler has executed.

Read also https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Change the setState arguments to functions which use the latest state automatically:

```
onSubmitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Check if first Name is returned empty
  if (this.state.user.name.trim().length === 0) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      errors: {
        ...state.errors,
        name: "This field is required"
      }
    }));
  }
  //Check if last name is returned empty
  if (this.state.user.surname.trim().length === 0) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      errors: {
        ...state.errors,
        surname: "This field is required"
      }
    }));
    return;
  }
}
```